# JQuery - Toggle Animate from Left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, slide

I'm trying to create the simplest jquery off-canvas menu toggle that I possibly can. There are tons of ways to do this, but I think we should be able to do it with as little as one line of code.

JQuery slide() allows you to toggle back and forth, with something like:
    $("myDiv").slideToggle();

So, shouldn't we be able to do something like:
    $("myDiv").animateToggle();

or:
    $("myDiv").animate(Toggle);

? I think that this would be logical, but nothing like this seems to exist.

You can animate() in one direction, but not toggle with the same button:
    $("myDiv").animate({left:"300px"});

Or maybe if slide() allowed us to choose left/right instead of top/bottom? You can fake it by animating width, but not position. That's not optimal, as you can see the contents collapsing with the width.

Any ideas out there? Something I'm missing?

Comment: so... you know how to do a slide animation, you're just not happy with how it's currently implemented in jQuery?

Comment: Don't animate width, animate `margin-left`

Comment: All `.slideToggle()` is is a wrapper around animate - if you want `slideLeftToggle()` then create `$.fn.slideLeftToggle(...` then it will be "one line of code" ... where you use it, same as `slideToggle` is "one line of code" (ie it's not, but where you use it, it is).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @freedom-m. I've attempted marginLeft animation at your suggestion. I can make it work in one direction, but I can't make it toggle. Any further insight into that?

Comment: Any other suggestions from anybody else? Bueller?